# Keyboard shortcut to view next page in Microsoft Word for Mac?

Tags: ms-office

Is there a keyboard shortcut to view the next page in Microsoft Word for Mac?
In Adobe Reader, when I press the **Right Arrow** key, the view jumps to the next page.
I am looking for something similar in Microsoft Word for Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word 2011 (the only version I have to test) <kbd>Command-page up</kbd> and <kbd>Command-page down</kbd> go to the top of the previous and next page respectively.

Unfortunately I don't have a Mac laptop with Office loaded to test but on my Apple keyboard <kbd>fn-command-up arrow</kbd> and <kbd>fn-command-down arrow</kbd> also work.

Comment: According to [Word for Mac 2011 keyboard shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/mac-word-help/word-keyboard-shortcuts-HA102929541.aspx) your answer is correct. Unfortunately, for some reason (probably a Microsoft bug?) this doesn't work on my computer. That's too bad for me!

Comment: Check in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts. Something else might be using it. Also do you have any software such as Alfred or Keyboard Maestro that could be grabbing the keystrokes.

Comment: I checked System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and didn't find a conflict with `Command-page up` or `Command-page down`. I also don't have Alfred or Keyboard Maestro as far as I know. Strange. Thanks for your help nonetheless!

Comment: Hmmm. Go to http://manytricks.com/keycodes/ and download the Key Codes utility. Does it show a key code of 0x79 for page down and fn-down arrow?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This sounds interesting, but given that I don't use Microsoft Word that often (mostly I use LaTeX) I will just live with the problem. One day if I have time, I will try the Key Codes utility and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On an extended keyboard, you can use "page up" and "page down" keys. Since you are asking the question, I assume you are on a laptop or have a standard keyboard.

In that case, you can use the function (`fn`) key along with the up and down arrows. It's not exactly the same since it also moves the cursor, but it will advance the view to the next or previous page.

Comment: That's actually wrong. In Word page up and page down move by a screen full.

Comment: Fair enough. I started on 80x24 terminals. The OP wanted "something similar" and the use of the fn key isn't obvious.